# What signal does docker emit when executing docker restart container?

Tags: docker

I tinkered an image together with my own entrypoint.
It starts several services. Starting with `docker run -it image` connects to the terminal and pressing C-c stops the container in less than 10 seconds.

But when I run: `docker restart container` docker kills the container after 10 seconds.

What signal is docker sending so that I can react on it?

Answer (score 1):

From https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stop/ :

> The main process inside the container will receive SIGTERM, and after a grace period, SIGKILL. The first signal can be changed with the STOPSIGNAL instruction in the container’s Dockerfile, or the --stop-signal option to docker run.

Comment: I listen on SIGTERM and SIGINT, but docker restart does not emit one of them.

Comment: Most probably the signal is not delivered to your process. Consider researching docker run --init and tini and TINI_KILL_PROCESS_GROUP . Either way, in a new question post an [MCVE] or it didn't happen.